# Autofac: Register component and resolve depending on resolving parent

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm wanting to register a component to resolve with parameters based on the class that it might be resolving for.  (That sounds a bit confusing, so I'll show an example).

Here's an object that uses a logger:

```
class MyObject : IMyObject
{
    public ILogger Logger;
    public MyObject(ILogger logger)
    {
        Logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Now the logger that is passed in COULD be different from class to class.  So I've got a rather patched idea for how to do that below:

```
class MyLogger : ILogger
{
    public string Name{get; protected set;}

    public static ILogger GetLogger(string className)
    {
        Name = className;
        MyLogger logger;
        // Do something to choose a logger for that specific class
        return logger;
    }
}
```

So when I register Logger I want to be able to tell it the className.  I'm hoping there's a way to do it similar to this:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.Register<MyLogger>(ctx =>
    {
        string className = //Get resolving class name somehow;
        return MyLogger.GetLogger(className);
    }).As<ILogger>();

builder.Register<MyObject>().As<IMyObject>();

var container = builder.Build();

IMyObject myObj = container.Resolve<IMyObject>();

//myObject.Logger.Name should now == "MyObject"
```

The reason I want to do it this way is to avoid registering each class I implement with a logger with autofac in code.  I want to be able to register all of the objects in xml, and simply have a LoggerModule, that adds this registration.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's what I do (ILog is just my own wrapper around log4net):

```
public class LoggingModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register((c, p) => GetLogger(p.TypedAs<Type>()));
    }

    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
        IComponentRegistry registry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing +=
            (sender, args) =>
            {
                var forType = args.Component.Activator.LimitType;

                var logParameter = new ResolvedParameter(
                    (p, c) => p.ParameterType == typeof (ILog),
                    (p, c) => c.Resolve<ILog>(TypedParameter.From(forType)));

                args.Parameters = args.Parameters.Union(new[] {logParameter});
            };
    }

    public static ILog GetLogger(Type type)
    {
        return new Log4NetLogger(type);
    }
}

public interface ILog
{
    void Debug(string format, params object[] args);
    void Info(string format, params object[] args);
    void Warn(string format, params object[] args);

    void Error(string format, params object[] args);
    void Error(Exception ex);
    void Error(Exception ex, string format, params object[] args);

    void Fatal(Exception ex, string format, params object[] args);
}

public class Log4NetLogger : ILog
{
    private readonly log4net.ILog _log;

    static Log4NetLogger()
    {
        XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }

    public Log4NetLogger(Type type)
    {
        _log = LogManager.GetLogger(type);
    }

    public void Debug(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        _log.DebugFormat(format, args);
    }

    public void Info(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        _log.InfoFormat(format, args);
    }

    public void Warn(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        _log.WarnFormat(format, args);
    }

    public void Error(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        _log.ErrorFormat(format, args);
    }

    public void Error(Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Error("", ex);
    }

    public void Error(Exception ex, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        _log.Error(string.Format(format, args), ex);
    }

    public void Fatal(Exception ex, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        _log.Fatal(string.Format(format, args), ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm attempting to implement your module, but I'm not finding the builder.Register() non-generic function.

Comment: It's an extension method that exists in `Autofac.RegistrationExtensions` class. You should definitely have it.

Comment: haha... nevermind... I didnt finish typing the code, and forgot that C# will imply the type from the Func.

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work well when resolving `IEnumerable`. `Limit` type is set to `IEnumerable<Interface>` instead of resolving each type separately.