# Accessing contextual information during lambda registration in Autofac?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

With Ninject I can do something like this:

```
Bind<ILogger>().ToMethod(context =>
{
    // Get type info
    var type = context.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType;
    var logger = new ConcreteLogger(type);

    Kernel.Get<IFoo>().DoFoo(logger);
    return logger;
});
```

How can I do this with Autofac?

This is the code I have:

```
 builder.Register(context => {
      var type = ?????
      var logger = new ConcreteLogger(type);

      context.Resolve<IFoo>().DoSomething(logger);
      return logger;
 }).As<ILogger>();
```

I can see in the debugger that `context` is actually of the type `Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup` which has a member `ComponentRegistration.Target` but I cannot access that because `InstanceLookup` is an internal class.

It appears I can do this, but it doesn't give me the type information of the class that requires this injected type:

```
 builder.Register(context => {
     var lookup = c as IInstanceLookup;
     var target = lookup.ComponentRegistration.Target as ComponentRegistration;
     var logger = new ConcreteLogger(target.Activator.LimitType);

      context.Resolve<IFoo>().DoSomething(logger);
      return logger;
 }).As<ILogger>();
```

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691583/autofac-register-component-and-resolve-depending-on-resolving-parent can help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to inject a component based on *"parent"* component. With *Autofac* you register components and these components doesn't known who need them.

By the way, you can do what you want by implementing a custom *Module*. Exemple :

```
public class TestModule : Module
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
        IComponentRegistry componentRegistry,
        IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Parameter parameter = new ResolvedParameter(
                (pi, c) =>
                {
                    return pi.ParameterType == typeof(ILogger);
                }, (pi, c) =>
                {
                    var p = new TypedParameter(typeof(Type), 
                                               e.Component.Activator.LimitType);
                    return c.Resolve<ILogger>(p);
                });

            e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(new Parameter[] { parameter });
        };
        base.AttachToComponentRegistration(componentRegistry, registration);
    }
}
```

and register the module like this :

```
builder.RegisterModule<TestModule>();
```

this way, each time a component will be resolved, it will add a new parameter knowing the type being constructed to create the `ILogger` dependency.

Be aware that by doing this you may have [captive dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/) : a dependency that was built for a component but used for another one. It can happens if your `ILogger` registration has a different scope, for example a singleton scope.

Comment: Thanks, this code is actually contained in a Module (it's being ported from Ninject who also stored it a NinjectModule).  I've managed to figure it out based on your suggestions.